# VBA code that uses checkbox to copy and paste entire row with data to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains several sheets with different types of inventory and one summary sheet.

I am trying to use checkboxes, that if checked as "True", will copy that row of data and paste into the summary sheet starting on a specific row. Each inventory sheet has several rows of differing data and I'd like users to be able to check multiple boxes they need on each sheet and this data to be copied to the summary sheet.

I found this code below that is working for the most part except it skips over some lines of data that are marked as "true". It also adds an unnecessary extra row between the lines once it copies the data over to the new sheet. What can I change so that all of the data marked "true" can be copied over and eliminate the extra rows?

Code I found is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJoRUwrEe0g

```
Sub CopyRowBasedOnCellValue()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    A = Worksheets("Exterior Items").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Customer Sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Customer Sheet").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Exterior Items").Range("B1:B" & A)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For B = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(B).Value) = "True" Then
        xRg(B).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Customer Sheet").Range("A" & B + 9)
        B = B + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Right now, you're manually incrementing the counter (`B` in this case) when the loop automatically does that for you as well. So you're doubling the increment when a match is made, which is why you're getting skips.

Comment: I suspect you actually want to increment a different value, let's say `C`, the ***output*** row number. You can use `B` as your ***input*** row number, but unless you want to have empty lines for the `False` rows, these need to stay independent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Copy_table_where_B_is_TRUE_row_by_row()

    'declarations
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    
    'reference source and destination sheets
    Set shtSource = Worksheets("Exterior Items")
    Set shtDestination = Worksheets("Customer Sheet")
    
    'find limits of tables present on source and destination sheets
    LastRowSource = shtSource.Cells(shtSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowDestination = shtDestination.Cells(shtDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'set output row index
    OutputRow = LastRowDestination + 1
    
    'using the source table..
    For Each rw In shtSource.Range("1:" & LastRowSource).Rows
        'if 2nd cell in row is TRUE
        If rw.Cells(2).Value = "True" Then
            'copy to destination sheet
            rw.Copy shtDestination.Cells(OutputRow, 1)
            'increment output row index
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

An entirely different method, that doesn't require any loops or counters would be to use a filter:

```
Sub Copy_filtered_table_where_B_is_TRUE()

    'declarations
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    
    'reference source and destination sheets
    Set shtSource = Worksheets("Exterior Items")
    Set shtDestination = Worksheets("Customer Sheet")
    
    'find limits of tables present on source and destination sheets
    '(these can be manually set if source table is fixed and destination location is fixed)
    LastRowSource = shtSource.Cells(shtSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowDestination = shtDestination.Cells(shtDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'using the source table..
    With shtSource.Range("1:" & LastRowSource)
    
        'apply a filter
        .AutoFilter
        
        'set filter to column 2 = True
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="True"
        
        'copy cells visible after application of filter, to next available row on destination sheet
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy shtDestination.Cells(LastRowDestination + 1, 1)
        
        'remove filter
        shtSource.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CLR thank you so much for the assistance! I tried your filter method as it makes so much more sense than just doing the loops/counters. Unfortunately I am getting a run-time error message:

Run-time error '1004'
Method "Autofilter' of object 'Range' failed

Do you know what may be causing this issue? Appreciate your time!

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get the 1004?

Comment: .Autofilter and the run-time error above pops up. I had also tried the first code that you had included above, that one didn't work at all unfortunately.

Comment: 1. If you hover over `LastRowSource`, what value appears. 2. If you manually go to the sheet, select from row 1 down to the bottom of the table and then apply a filter, does it return an error?